# Do descending __key__ indexes cost additional write ops?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to learn exactly how various types of indexes impact the number of Write Ops required for each entity. I thought I had it pretty much figured out, but then I found a case that threw me for a loop.

I have a root User entity with a number of GameSummary child entities that have a timestamp and a bunch of other stat fields (think player name, score, etc).

My goal is to be able to query for a list of GameSummaries for all Users or for a specific User. The results should all be sorted in descending order by timestamp and I may want to add a search feature later on that adds equality filters on some of the other GameSummary fields and returns the results in the same sorted order. This is all fairly straight-forward, but I'd obviously like to do this with as few indexes as possible.

Using a default index on the timestamp property creates two indexes (ascending and descending), but I only need one of those indexes, so the other write is just overhead. My first thought was to set the property as "noindex" (Indexed=False in python) and then add the descending index I needed in index.yaml. This ends up not working, presumably because the query planner tries to use the default index anyway and just returns no results.

It then occurred to me that if I used the timestamp as the entity key I could sort by __key__ (which doesn't have default indexes) and add only the indexes I actually need. I'm running the dev server with --require_indexes, which caused my queries to fail (as expected) until I added these two indexes:

```
- kind: GameSummary
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc

- kind: GameSummary
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

At this point I looked at the Datastore Viewer in the admin console and noticed that the Write Ops column for my GameSummaries was only 2 (Entities and EntitiesByKind). I was expecting to see a count of 5 here (1 more for the first index and 2 more for the ancestor index). According to the dev server, though, it seems that I'm getting the descending __key__ index writes for free?

Is the admin console lying to me? Or am I missing some quirk of indexes on the __key__ property?

Even stranger, adding indexes with additional properties that sort on the __key__ like these:

```
- kind: GameSummary
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: Player
  - name: Enemy
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc

- kind: GameSummary
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: Player
  - name: Enemy
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

doesn't increase the Write Ops for GameSummary entities either. I could maybe see some magic happening with the simple case, but this makes it seem more and more like a bug in the dev server to me.

Comment: I would start by asking why you are using a timestamp as the key? In the (admittedly unlikely) event that two entities are written with the exact same timestamp, you would probably get an error from App Engine. Also, the `__key__` does in fact get indexed automatically but only in ascending order (otherwise, it would be pretty slow to fetch by ID I guess).

Comment: Since the GameSummary objects have a User parent, it would be OK if multiple entities had the same timestamp as long as they weren't from the same User. In practice, a single User shouldn't be able to play two games at the exact same time to be able to duplicate timestamps, so I'm not concerned about conflicts in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just confirmed that this is an sdk bug, you should probably report this if it doesn't exists. I tested it with appstats on live server and it is adding an extra write on adding descending order index.

But as a tip since I have encountered the same thing to avoid multiple indexes and always order by post time on descending order, you can do a bit shift operation on your timestamp and store its hexadecimal + a random number to avoid conflicts. It has worked for me without problems. Although my exact usage was that I really had my own counter instead of timestamp but for project spec reasons.

Comment: Thanks for testing on live servers. I went ahead and created a new [Issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10397) for the bug if anybody else finds this question and wants to track that.